# can an SVG viewbox be inside an HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a simple block moving game where the mouse is a black square. I was just planning on using html, css, javascript, and jQuery, but it's been pretty difficult. I can make different squares move across the screen in an html Canvas tag, but the only way I've been able to make the mouse a square is with an svg tag.

```
<svg id="svg-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30" onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
     <rect class="draggable" fill="#000" x="2" y="" width="2" height="2" transform="rotate(90, 5, 5) translate(10, 0)"/>
</svg>
```

Then I'll set the object to draggable, and the cursor to none upon dragging the square.Here's the script:

```
function makeDraggable(evt) {
    var svg = evt.target;

    svg.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);

    svg.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('touchmove', drag);


    function getMousePosition(evt) {
    var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
    if (evt.touches) { evt = evt.touches[0]; }
    return {
        x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
        y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
    };
    }

    var selectedElement, offset, transform;

    function startDrag(evt) {
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('draggable')) {
        selectedElement = evt.target;
        offset = getMousePosition(evt);

        // Make sure the first transform on the element is a translate transform
        var transforms = selectedElement.transform.baseVal;

        if (transforms.length === 0 || transforms.getItem(0).type !== SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE) {
        // Create an transform that translates by (0, 0)
        var translate = svg.createSVGTransform();
        translate.setTranslate(0, 0);
        selectedElement.transform.baseVal.insertItemBefore(translate, 0);
        }

        // Get initial translation
        transform = transforms.getItem(0);
        offset.x -= transform.matrix.e;
        offset.y -= transform.matrix.f;
    }
    }

    function drag(evt) {
    if (selectedElement) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var coord = getMousePosition(evt);
        transform.setTranslate(coord.x - offset.x, coord.y - offset.y);
    }
    }

    function endDrag(evt) {
    selectedElement = false;
    }
}
```

I know for a fact there's a simpler way to do it, but this is my brute force method. Anyways, if anyone has a better way of doing it that'd be great. Otherwise, any ideas to go about this. I tried setting properties to lay the viewBox over the canvas, but it doesn't want to work. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have an svg to draw a square on a canvas.
Here's a great article on how to draw an object following your cursor: https://www.kirupa.com/canvas/follow_mouse_cursor.htm

Here's an example for a square:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasPos = getPosition(canvas);
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition, false);
 
 function setMousePosition(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;
}
 

function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(mouseX-25, mouseY-25, 50, 50);
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  context.fill();
 
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}       
update();  

function getPosition(el) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;
 
  while (el) {
    xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  cursor:none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="550px" height="350px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Well I should've asked you before I did all of that research. Thanks for the help! this works perfectly, I just need to hide the pointer when the block follows it.

Comment: To add on to that, can you style the objects created? Or how would I set the cursor to none when it's in the area of the object?

Comment: I've hidden the cursor by adding `#myCanvas {cursor:none}`. You can then style the objects created, you have a lot of options.

Comment: I know what you mean Diogo, but I still would've needed to bind an object inside of canvas to the cursor. Thanks for your help though